# Generating repetitive code in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics

I was curious if there was someway for Netbeans or some other application to generate repetitive code for me.

`tf.add(squareTextField1)
tf.add(squareTextField2)
tf.add(squareTextField3)`
etc.

all the squareTextField variables are instance fields declared at a class level and only differ in name by the number at the end. I really would rather not write this same line 81 times.

Comment: Why have you stored them as 81 different instance fields rather than putting them in an array in the first place that can be easily iterated over?

Comment: When i had the same needs, I've written a simple program to print that, and I've copied from the console

Comment: If you want to name your variables {{somthing}}{{index}} then rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste are still the fastest way to do it :(

However 81 is a LOT of text fields.  I suggest you have a look at [reflection](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/) and use that to treat your fields as an array.

Answer (score 0):

When I rewrite more than 3 times similar phrases my obviuous conclusion is: "There is a way to can do it with a loop".

```
    String [] squareTextField = {"A", "B", "D", ...};

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tf.add(squareTextField[i]);
    }
```